# In Adi Shankaracharya's "Shiva Panchakshara Stotra," Yajna-Svaruupaaya or Yaksha-Svaruupaaya, which is correct?

Tags: shiva, adi-shankaracharya, stotra

In the penultimate verse of phalasruthi of *Shiva Panchakshara Stotra* written by Adi Shankaracharya,

Yajñasvarūpāya {Yakṣasvarūpāya} jaṭādharāya
pinākahastāya sanātanāya ।
divyāya devāya digambarāya
tasmai ya_kārāya namaḥ śivāya ॥5॥

There are two variations Yajna-Svarūpāya and Yaksha-Svarūpāya; which one is likely to be the correct one?

Comment: The variation that I am aware of is - yaksha svarupaya. This is most probably a reference to the Kena upanishad allegory, where brahman assumes the form of a yaksha to teach the gods a lesson after they became filled with pride. This verse is most likely praising Shiva as that brahman in the form of yaksha. Alternately, there is nothing wrong in saying that Shiva as brahman, is also yajna svarupa.